# Pandas filter out a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe column which looks like the following:

DF

```
Terms
Dan Will, Python
Dan Will, Work 
Python, Work
Internet, Job
Dan King, Work
```

However, I only want it to show outputs if it contains a name then a keyword after it as below:

```
Terms
Dan Will, Python
Dan Will, Work
Dan King, Work
```

I have a list of the names already from the dataframe

DFFullName

is it possible to search the column and delete out the rows that dont contain any of the names?

Comment: How do you know what is a name or what is a key word?   Let's take Julia for example?  Julia is a programming language.

Comment: I have a list of the names? if that helps? it is possible to search if the names are in the column and if not delete them out

Comment: Yep, include that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we should have a list of name

```
name = ['Dan Will']
```

Then do `split`

```
s = df.Terms.str.split(', ',expand=True)
out = df[s[0].isin(name) & ~s[1].isin(name)]
out
Out[70]: 
              Terms
0  Dan Will, Python
1    Dan Will, Work
```

Comment: How would this work with a list of names? for multiple searches? as it didn't appear to work when i just tried it?

Comment: Do i need to add out back into a column?

Comment: updated question to show more than 1 name

Comment: @Will this solution will work for list of name , just change the name to your list of name ~

Comment: Search_List = dfFullName1.values.tolist()
s = Extracted_Results_df.new_results1.str.split(', ',expand=True)
out = Extracted_Results_df[s[0].isin(Search_List) & ~s[1].isin(Search_List)]

print(out)

Comment: Only matches on the 1 name in the list even though there are 3 in there that should match

Comment: Ignore me. Managed to fix it. Error on my part. Thank you